# Child from the relations Yael had with Sisra

Tags: children-parenting, historical-figures, shoftim--book-of, masechet-yevamot, yael

According to [Shoftim 5:27](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15813#v=27), per the explanation found in [Yevamos 103a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=103&format=pdf) (in the name of רבי יוחנן), Yael had relations with Sisra.

> אמר רבי יוחנן שבע בעילות בעל אותו רשע באותו היום שנאמר בין רגליה כרע
>   נפל שכב בין רגליה כרע נפל באשר כרע שם נפל שדוד
>
> R. Johanan Said: That profligate (Sisera) had seven sexual connections
>   on that day; for it is said ([Shoftim 5:27](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15813#v=27)), Between her feet he sunk, he fell, he
>   lay; at her feet he sunk, he fell; where he sunk there he fell down
>   dead.

(*Soncino translation*)

Did she bear a son from these relations? If so, was he a prophet?

Comment: Why would you suspect he was a prophet?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Maybe from another mother? Not a must from Yael...

Comment: Interestingly the Midrash disputes the Gemara and claims that they didn't have relations.

Answer (score 16):

[Gitin 57b](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9639&st=&pgnum=114&hilite=) says that the grandchildren of Sisra taught children in Yerushalayim. [Rabbi Tzadok HaCohen in Poked Ikrim -  Os 5 - page 36 - line 3 - second columm](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14377&st=&pgnum=36&hilite=) says that this Gemara, according to the teachings of הרמ"ע is talking about grandchildren that came from the relations Yael had with Sisra. I do not know whether she had a son or daughter nor whether they were prophets.

Comment: +1. R' Tzadok is referring to *Asara Ma'amaros* ([*Chikur Din* 5:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45098&st=&pgnum=180)). The רמ"ע מפאנו follows R' Nissim Gaon's *girsa* of *Sanhedrin* 96b that R' Akiva descended from Sisera (*B'rachos* 27b, נוקי לר' עקיבא לית ליה זכות אבות. איתה בסנהדרין בפרק כל ישראל יש להן חלק (דף צו) מבני בניו של סיסרא למדו תורה בירושלים ומאן אינון ר' עקיבא).

Answer (score 1):

In Sefer Ezra 2:53 and Nechemia 7:55 there is mention of the children of Sisera. It does not indicate if these are children from his liaison with Yael or what their gender may have been. Those children are enumerated as part of the water drawers who come from the Giveonim, ostensibly not prophets.